# Website not indexed/scraped/crawled via Bing Custom Search

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-search

I want to create a multi-site search function using Bing Custom Search. I have created a search instance on https://www.customsearch.ai/ using my company-provided Microsoft account.

After adding my company's main www website (`www.mysite.com`) the search works, in the try-it-out tool and when going via the v7 API.

When I add a subsite, e.g. ``mysubsite.mysite.com`, how ever it does not crawl and display search results from that site.

I have tried:

- Allowing subpages for `mysite.com`
- Specifying protocol, e.g. HTTPS
- Waiting for a day or two

What can be the problem? Sure, the subsite is not publicly released yet (or announced I mean), but it is accessible by everyone with an Internet connection and a web browser. How come Bing Custom Search does not find it when I tell it the exact address?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your subsite/pages are not crawled or indexed, you can check out the webmaster info on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/define-your-custom-view. Search for **webmaster documentation** on this page.